# dB/s/Hz in spectrum efficiency

Tags: wireless-communication, signal-processing

Here is link of research paper in which spectrum efficiency is given in terms of dB/s/Hz. How can we define it?

https://jwcn-eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13638-016-0792-0

Answer (score 1):

As with any physical equation, the units of a constant, in this case "spectrum efficiency," are chosen so that the final result is in the units desired.  So, if you're going for an answer in dB, then somewhere in this equation you'll multiply this constant by time (s , seconds) and a bandwidth in Hz.